# Which one is better (in support, difficulty, ...) to develop a plugin, Netbeans or Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, netbeans

I would like to make a new plugin for a programming language because there is not any IDE the time I asked this question. I think IDE developing is far more easier if I try to use one of the available platform like Netbeans or Eclipse or ...
As I checked, Eclipse plugin (if that plugin is not updated) won't be able to start up after 1 or 2 years. I mean, Eclipse develops a way that old plugins has to follow in order to hold the compatibility.

Comment: You have no long-term guarantees with either IDE - Oracle could cancel future Netbeans development for all we know.  Numbers say that Eclipse is the dominant IDE for Java.

Comment: Yes, it's true. Oracle will hold these open source projects as far as I know, but from year to year, Eclipse gets bigger and bigger.

Thanks to you all, I close this question now. I think I will choose Eclipse after some further readings approve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I also can answer only 1/2 of your question.

I have developed (small) eclipse plugins and an eclipse RCP.  Both were a breeze.  I agree with @Zoltan's comment, get your dependencies right & don't use some back-door unsupported feature in aplugin you don't control & your problems should be minimal.  Even if you did run into a dependency problem, the configuration is straightforward enough that you could make an updated release of your plugin very quickly.

Comment: Thanks for both of you replying to my question. I would love to start developing this plugin with Eclipse, however after some browsing in both sites, I found a programming language extension tutorial plugin for Netbeans and it could be a great advantage for Netbeans.
I still don't know which one to choose but I think it isn't an easy question so it worth to wait.

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer your original question as I have not developed for Netbeans.

As the backwards compatibility, if the version dependencies are set right, and only the API from other plug-ins are used, the old plug-in should work (there are some exceptions, but in that case upgrading the plug-in does not take too much effort, as there is documentation about what has changed).

The main drawback in Eclipse development is that documentation is sometimes scarce, but for common tasks there is some available.